# Changing values in multiple columns of a pandas DataFrame using known column values

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
Knownvalue    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
  17.3413     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  33.4534     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

what I wanna do is that when Knownvalue is between 0-10, A is changed from 0 to 1. And when Knownvalue is between 10-20, B is changed from 0 to 1,so on so forth.

It should be like this after changing:

```
Knownvalue     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
   17.3413     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
   33.4534     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
```

Anyone know how to apply a method to change it?

Comment: (Note: text is much more convenient than images, because you can copy and paste text.  Accordingly I've reverted to the text versions.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I first bucket the `Knownvalue` Series into a list of integers equal to its truncated value divided by ten (e.g. 27.87 // 10 = 2).  These buckets represent the integer for the desired column location.  Because the `Knownvalue` is in the first column, I add one to these values.

Next, I enumerate through these bin values which effectively gives me tuple pairs of row and column integer indices.  I use `iat` to set the value of the these locations equal to 1.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create some sample data.
df_vals = pd.DataFrame({'Knownvalue': np.random.random(5) * 50})
df = pd.concat([df_vals, pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))], axis=1)

# Create desired column locations based on the `Knownvalue`.
bins = (df.Knownvalue // 10).astype('int').tolist()
>>> bins
[4, 3, 0, 1, 0]

# Set these locations equal to 1.
for idx, col in enumerate(bins):
    df.iat[idx, col + 1] = 1  # The first column is the `Knownvalue`, hence col + 1

>>> df
   Knownvalue  A  B  C  D  E
0   47.353937  0  0  0  0  1
1   37.460338  0  0  0  1  0
2    3.797964  1  0  0  0  0
3   18.323131  0  1  0  0  0
4    7.927030  1  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Could you explain" for n, c in enumerate(idx):
    df.iat[n, c + 1] = 1" ?

Comment: @ZixuanZhang what he's doing with the `idx` variable is to check if `Knownvalue` is less than 10 convert to 0, greater than 10 but less than 20 convert to 1 so on and forth. He's doing that by applying `floor` function  which take a float and rounds it down. `enumerate` takes the the list of `idx` and provide you with the `index` and `value` which are assigned to `n` and `c` respectively. From that he's assigning `1` to their respective dataframe column using `iat`.

Comment: @Leb I have just figured it out myself! Thanks for the specific explanation any way!

Answer (score 4):

A different approach would be to reconstruct the frame from the Knownvalue column using [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
>>> import string
>>> new_cols = pd.get_dummies(df["Knownvalue"]//10).loc[:,range(8)].fillna(0)
>>> new_cols.columns = list(string.ascii_uppercase)[:len(new_cols.columns)]
>>> pd.concat([df[["Knownvalue"]], new_cols], axis=1)
   Knownvalue  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
0     17.3413  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
1     33.4534  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
```

`get_dummies` does the hard work:

```
>>> (df.Knownvalue//10)
0    1
1    3
Name: Knownvalue, dtype: float64
>>> pd.get_dummies((df.Knownvalue//10))
   1  3
0  1  0
1  0  1
```